# What is the purpose of the `Ecto.Schema.Metadata`? (i.e., the `__meta__` field)

Tags: elixir, schema, ecto

I am planning to use `Ecto`'s `Schema` and `Changeset` only for validation without persisting anything to a database, and trying to figure out whether I should use [`Ecto.Schema.schema/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/Ecto.Schema.html#schema/2)or [`Ecto.Schema.embedded_schema/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/Ecto.Schema.html#embedded_schema/1). According to the docs the only difference between them is that "*An embedded schema does not require a source name and it does not include a metadata field.*"

So I went with `embedded_schema/1`, works wonderfully, but it left me wondering **what the metadata is exactly used for?** The [`Ecto.Schema.Metadata` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/Ecto.Schema.Metadata.html) are not much help to clarify this:

> Stores metadata of a struct.
>
> The fields are:
>
> - state - the state in a struct’s lifetime, one of :built, :loaded,
>   :deleted
> - source - the source for the schema alongside the query
>   prefix, defaults to {nil, "source"}
> - context - context stored by the
>   database

Doing a search for "**meta**" yields no results, and "metadata" comes back with one result in the [`Ecto.Schema` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/Ecto.Schema.html), which is in the line quoted above for `embedded_schema/1`.

---

UPDATE

Forgot that Ecto 3 is coming out soon and the Hexdocs documentation is still for Ecto 2.2.11. Found [the updated `Metadata` docs](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/33d91e5749f82efe6e809455e94bc03fc4d48f27/lib/ecto/schema/metadata.ex) in the source though that are more verbose:

```
 Stores metadata of a struct.  

  ## State

  The state of the schema is stored in the `:state` 
  field and allows following values:

    * `:built` - the struct was constructed in 
                 memory and is not persisted
                 to database yet;

    * `:loaded` - the struct was loaded from database 
                  and represents persisted data;

    * `:deleted` - the struct was deleted and no longer
                   represents persisted data.

  ## Source
  The `:source` tracks the (table or collection) where
  the struct is or should be persisted to.

  ## Prefix
  Tracks the source prefix in the data storage.

  ## Context
  The `:context` field represents additional state some 
  databases require for proper updates of data. It is 
  not used by the built-in adapters of `Ecto.Adapters.Postres` 
  and `Ecto.Adapters.MySQL`.

  ## Schema
  The `:schema` field refers the module name for the 
  schema this metadata belongs to.
```

([The updated `Schema` docs](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/33d91e5749f82efe6e809455e94bc03fc4d48f27/lib/ecto/schema.ex) also resolve my dilemma above:

```
  An Ecto schema is used to map any data source into an Elixir struct.
  The definition of the schema is possible through two main APIs:
  `schema/2` and `embedded_schema/1`.

  `schema/2` is typically used to map data from a persisted source,
  usually a database table, into Elixir structs and vice-versa. For
  this reason, the first argument of `schema/2` is the source (table)
  name. Structs defined with `schema/2` also contain a `__meta__` field
  with metadata holding the status of the struct, for example, if it
  has been built, loaded or deleted.

  On the other hand, `embedded_schema/1` is used for defining schemas
  that are embedded in other schemas or only exist in-memory. For example,
  you can use such schemas to receive data from a command line interface
  and validate it, without ever persisting it elsewhere. Such structs
  do not contain a `__meta__` field, as they are never persisted.
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ecto.Schema.Metadata` is used solely to store all the database-related information.

As José mentioned in the [series of posts on Ecto 2 → 3](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2018/10/a-sneak-peek-at-ecto-3-0-breaking-changes/),

> Since Ecto 2.0, an increased number of developers and teams have been using Ecto for data mapping and validation, without a need for a database. However, adding Ecto to your application would still bring a lot of the SQL baggage, such as adapters, sandboxes and migrations, which many considered to be a mixed message.

The latter is all about the metadata.

There is a rule of thumb for Ecto 2: whether you need the DB *table* behind, use `schema`; use `embedded_schema` otherwise.

---

*Sidenote:* my general advice would be when you want to understand something in a nutshell, don’t read docs, [read the code](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.11/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L285).

Answer (score 0):

The `__meta__` field is used by Ecto internally to maintain metadata about the record, associations, if they're loaded, stale or more.

The description in the documentation you linked seems self-sufficient:

> **Stores metadata of a struct.**
>
> The fields are:
>
> - `state` - the state in a struct's lifetime, one of `:built`,
>         `:loaded`, `:deleted`
> - `source` - the source for the schema alongside the query prefix,
>         defaults to `{nil, "source"}`
> - `context` - context stored by the database